# How can I use array_search with array_chunk?

Tags: php

I want to search and delete `$srch_data` data from the `$list`, but `array_search()` is not working. What's going wrong?

```
$srch_data = 'neha,neha@xyz.com'; 

$list = "gaurav,gaurav@xyz.com,neha,neha@xyz.com,ayush,ayush@xyz.com";
$arr = explode(',',$list);
$list_array = array_chunk($arr,2);

$pos = array_search($srch_data,$list_array);
echo $pos;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching with different things.  Once you have used `array_chunk()`, your data is...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => gaurav
            [1] => gaurav@xyz.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => neha
            [1] => neha@xyz.com
        )
...
```

and you are searching for

```
'neha,neha@xyz.com'
```

so this will not match.

If you converted your search string to an array as well, this will work...

```
$pos = array_search(explode(",", $srch_data),$list_array);
```

Comment: Also `strpos` can be used if order of values is the same, then no exploding needed.

Comment: @u_mulder, TBH not sure if it's the best way to do this anyway- but `strpos` could work with a bit of extra work (in case it was `aneha,neha@xyz.com` in the original string).

Comment: Yep, this could be the issue.